# Multiline placeholder that only disappears when row changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

Helo there!

I'm trying to figure out a simple way of doing multiline placeholders inside a textarea (or an alternative solution, more about that in the bottom) that only disappears when the row have changes. So, basically, if this is the initial state of the textarea (or whatever it can be)

```
Write a question here
Write another question here
Write the third question here
```

And the user clicks the first question and types `A` it would look like this:

```
A
Write another question here
Write the third question here
```

I've thought about three different solutions so far but not sure which one to prefer.

1) Have ghost content that is rendered separately from the area of text.

2) Instead of using a textarea, have one input per line that the textarea would be. Problem would be to implement textarea behavior but with many inputs instead. Having placeholders per line would be trivial though.

3) Have actual text and use a parser of some kind to add/remove text whenever that is needed.

Appreciate any help/pointers I can get.

I'm using React and Redux but I'm happy to get answers that are including other technologies that I can take inspiration from.

Comment: I would go with 2). But what textarea behaviour are you referring to?

Comment: @Repo things like if you press on up arrow, it has to jump to the input box above, if you press on tab it inserts a tab instead of jumping to the next input box and similar things... But thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @Repo One thing I'm worried about now if I go with 2 is that how do I deal with people wanting to select multiple lines of text?

Comment: Jumping up and down is easy enough ( just ask my kid =) ). But selecting multiple lines will be a challenge. But I still think that you need separate inputs for separate questions. The data will be much easier to handle.